# Mistfall village is empty!

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I am working on Tricks and Treats of Pandaria, and the village of Mistfall has no people, no quest markers and no pumpkin.

As a freshly flying level 90, what are the steps I must take to reveal the people of Mistfall village?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mistfall Village is phased and is tied to the first set of quests related to the [Golden Lotus](http://www.wowhead.com/faction=1269) faction and its set of daily quests.

To start the Golden Lotus quest chain in the Vale of Eternal Blossoms, head to the Golden Pagoda in the middle of the Vale where you'll find the starting NPC. However, if you didn't open the gate to the Vale via the questline in Kun-Lai Summit, you'll need to do that as well: it starts with a visit to the Temple of the White Tiger ([alliance](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=31392), [horde](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=31393)). Blizzard recognized the Golden Lotus faction was confusing, so they even [created a guide](http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/5616721859#1):

> - At level 87, go speak to Anduin/Dezco at the Temple of the White Tiger in Kun-Lai Summit and complete “A Celestial Experience.” ([alliance](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=31394), [horde](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=31395))
> - Accept the follow-up quest, “A Witness to History.” ([alliance](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=31512), [horde](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=31511))
> - Find Anduin/Dezco at the big gate north of the Vale. This will start a cinematic that opens the gates.
> - Turn in “A Witness to History” to [Zhi the Harmonious](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=59905) at the Golden Pagoda in the center of Vale of Eternal Blossoms.
> - Accept and complete the follow-up quest, “[The Shrine of Two Moons](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=30649),” and “[The Shrine of Seven Stars](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=30631)” (Horde/Alliance respectively).
> - If you're not level 90 you'll receive no further quests.
> - At level 90 you should return and pick up the quest chain again. *Note that you must have trained flying to proceed.*

> - Pick up “[The Ruins of Guo-Lai](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=31296)” and complete it.
> - This leads to “[Out with the Scouts](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=30633)” and “[Barring Entry](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=30634).”
> - This leads to “[Killing the Quilen](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=30635)” and “[Stones of Power](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=30636).” While in the ruins, you should also get “The Guo-Lai Halls.” If you don't get this quest near the entrance to the crypt, you can return to Anji Autumnlight to get this quest.
> - These 3 quests must be completed before you can complete “[Leaving an Opening](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=30638).”
> - Turn in “Leaving an Opening” at the Golden Pagoda, and this should lead straight into the dailies.

Doing the entire quest line to the point you get a set of daily quest should guarantee its phasing, but [a post on the official forums](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/6934953599#9) indicates that you might be able to get it to phase by completing only a subset of the quests by finding a quest marker in the Guo-Lai Halls.

However, reportedly [Blizzard intended](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/6935294274#4) people to be able to complete the achievement without unlocking the Golden Lotus dailies, but it's been bugged and may not be fixed in time for the completion of the Hallow's End event. Unlocking the dailies should guarantee its availability.

Comment: I have opened the gate, and the Golden Pagoda quest giver isn't giving me a quest.

Comment: @DavidB the Golden Lotus faction quest chains are convoluted; so much so that Blizzard was forced to create [a guide](http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/5616721859#1). You may be missing a different pre-requisite: I'd double check the guide to see what you're missing.

Comment: In my case, I had not completed "Shrine of Seven Stars".